# MFC Visual c++ Persist the size of docking panes on close and reopen?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-2010, panes

Hi I would like to know the methods in which dockable pane sizes in MFC can be persisted over sessions?
Like the class to use or documentation relating to that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By default, **MFC Feature Pack** based application automatically saves the current states of windows, ribbons, menus and toolbars to the registry when application exits, and loads them at startup. This is implemented in `SaveState()` and `LoadState()` methods of `CWinAppEx` class.

Comment: Read MSDN documentation.

Comment: can even the sizes of individual docking pane be  saved ?

Comment: Yes it does save the size and location of each individual docking bar/pane.